# How can I remove a property when using media queries?

Tags: css, media-queries

Without media queries I have something like this:

```
 .sample_div {
      left: 200px;
 }
```

When I have a 780px media query, I want to do the following:

```
 .sample_div {
      right: 300px;
 }
```

The problem is that the left is showing in the 780px media query.  How can I only show right and not left in that one?

Comment: @Dre yup tried that but it doesn't do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [left specifications on W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_left.asp)

This should work for you:

```
.sample_div {
     left: auto;
     right: 300px;
}
```

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't do anything.  It remains in the same position it shows it in.